# Cannot generate subsets of feature class with arcpy (ArcGIS library in Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, gis, arcgis, arcpy

I'm having a hard time here on processing GIS data in Python, using library ArcPy. 
I've been trying to generate independent features from a feature class based on a field of the attribute table which is a unique code representing productive forest units, but I can't get it done. 
I've already done this in other situations, but this time I don't know what I am missing. 
Here is the code and the error I get:

```
# coding utf-8
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
ws = r'D:\Projeto_VANT\SIG\proc_parc.gdb'
arcpy.env.workspace = ws

talhoes = r'copy_talhoes'

estados = ('SP', 'MG')
florestas = ('PROPRIA', 'PARCERIA')

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(talhoes,
                                          'talhoes_layer',
                                          """ "ESTADO" IN {} AND "FLORESTA" IN {} """.format(estados, florestas),
                                          ws)
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(in_features = 'talhoes_layer',
                                            out_path = ws,
                                            out_name = 'talhoes1')
talhoes1 = r'talhoes1'

arcpy.AddField_management(talhoes1, 'CONCAT_T', 'TEXT')
arcpy.CalculateField_management(talhoes1, 'CONCAT_T', """ [ESTADO] & "_" & [CODIGO] & "_" & [TALHAO] """, 'VB')

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(talhoes1, ['CONCAT_T', 'AREA']) as tal_cursor:
    for x in tal_cursor:
        print(x[0] + " " + str(x[1])) # This print is just to check if the cursor works and it does!
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(x,
                                          'teste',
                                          """ CONCAT_T = '{}' """.format(str(x[0]))) # Apparently the problem is here!
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management('teste',
                                      'Layer{}'.format(x[0]))
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/ArcPy_Classes/Scripts/sampling_sig.py", line 32, in <module>
    """ CONCAT_T = '{}' """.format(str(x[0])))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 6965, in MakeFeatureLayer
    raise e
RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

Comment: Cross-posted: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/365756/8104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with your **In** feature. you will want your in feature to be **talhoes1** since x is the cursor object and not a feature.

```
  arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(talhoes1,'teste',""" CONCAT_T = 
  '{}'""".format(str(x[0])))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I've posted this question at https://gis.stackexchange.com and they already helped me. But thanks anyway, you were the only one that aswered my question!

Comment: Yea, I have found the GIS stack exchange to be better for GIS related questions.